# You have died from... 'Bad Luck'... What actually killed me?

Tags: battlefield-3, punkbuster

I have died from multiple opponents and near by explosions.  Sometimes, these causes cannot be traced by the battlefield 3 system and, therefore, I get prompted 'Bad Luck'.

Usually, I am okay with this as environmental causes that I cannot control in the battlefield - but is DICE killing me because they think I am cheating?  DICE recently released information that  [they are cracking down on cheaters](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/news/view/2832654777784564141/).  I am grateful for their crackdown - as cheaters can ruin games - but I have heard through the grapevine that DICE will kill you if they 'think' you are cheating ( some automated system built into BF3 to autokill you if you go on a massive kill streak).  Example:

I was flying a jet, which just randomly exploded: Bad Luck. This was after a good, legit air dominance. I confirmed with server admins that they did not kill me (with any server administrative tools).  They told me that DICE will just do that once in a while.

Can anyone confirm that this exists in battlefield 3 or not?

Comment: Good question. Happened to me quite a few times as well. Some were understandable (could have died from falling debris in a cave/house etc), but when it occurs right after spawning in an open area with no other players nearby, one starts to wonder :)

Comment: I play on 360 and I find that sometimes I am running and I just get iced by bad luck. I'm not sure if they're correlated but its annoying.

Comment: You need an account in Origin to access that link :/

Comment: it's also entirely conceivable that the server admins were lying to you, btw.

Comment: There wass something similar in Halo (2?) which essentially meant you were a victim of the map. You are killed by anything from a glitch in the map, falling off the edge, or to an unfortunate ricochet not attributed to another player.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "Killed by the Guardians" is what you're referring to, and that wasn't for environment kills (that was usually just referred to as "suicide"), but for deaths that the game otherwise couldn't explain.  Pretty on the money with what OP is describing, really.

Comment: @Ketura yep thats the one!

Comment: This happened to me last night.  I was playing a TDM on Firestorm and I was running across an open area (no falling debris or un-exploded fuel tanks). I hear what sounds like a bullet and I died due to bad luck.  Very strange.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For example, if you are killed by a secondary explosion -- if you are standing next to a fuel truck that blows up -- that is a Bad Luck death.

Similarly getting killed by unmanned moving vehicles (say the driver hopped out while the vehicle is in motion) or flying debris is also Bad Luck.

Comment: or it could be a player called bad luck :O

Comment: I'd like to see the kill cam of the player "bad luck" sometimes.

Comment: I was flying jet, health was regenerating, then i randmly blow up from bad luck, noone else around me, no debris or anything. WTF is going on?

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure there's not any built in kill streak trigger. I've seen hackers ring up over 200 kills without a death.

If bad luck is not from something obvious (like an unmanned vehicle hitting you), I would say it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Dying from "Bad Luck" is basically dying from something another player did not initiate non-suicidal.

Antenna on Capsian Border falls on you-> Bad Luck
Sit in fire too long -> Bad Luck

Comment: They really just need to call some of the Bad Luck deaths as Stupidity. I.E. I died by my own grenade, Either Natural Selection occured with <PlayerName> or <PlayerName> was killed by his/her own stupidity.